# Angular mat-select not picking up default value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a array object of the form

```
interArray = [{key: "0", value: "1949"},
              {key: "1", value: "2919"},
              {key: "2", value: "4009"},
              {key: "3", value: "6119"},
              {key: "4", value: "7649"},
              {key: "5", value: "9169"}];
```

My HTML file contains the following:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="IntransitSelectedValue">
  <mat-option [value]="option.value" *ngFor="let option of interArray" selected>
    {{option.value}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

And my angular component code this is the scenario:

I'm using `IntransitSelectedValue` in Angular component to read the value and make some manipulations.

I need to pass `value: "2919"` or any value which will be returned based on some logic & that value Eg: `2919` I need to pass to Angular as a default dropdown to be shown, in this Eg it will be `2919` selected and rest. But nay attempt I was not able to set the default value to preselect

I tried adding `selected = "2919"` in angular component and in html adding  `<mat-select [(value)] = selected>` but it didn't work.

Comment: Remove `formControlName`, You are using both [Template driven form](https://angular.io/guide/forms) and [Reactive form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) together.

Comment: Removed but I think that is not impacting

Comment: Hav you assigned the default value as `this.IntransitSelectedValue = "2919"`. Here is a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbg9dc?file=src/app/select-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using two way binding to read a value, just give it a initial value to you **IntransitSelectedValue**

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  IntransitSelectedValue: any = '2919';

  interArray = [{key: "0", value: "1949"},
                {key: "1", value: "2919"},
                {key: "2", value: "4009"},
                {key: "3", value: "6119"},
                {key: "4", value: "7649"},
                {key: "5", value: "9169"}];
}
```

then with the two way binding **[(ngModel)]="IntransitSelectedValue"** angular knows that the initial value of the select will be equal to **IntransitSelectedValue** in this case is **'2919'**